# Array contains NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, null, expression

I'm trying to select the last `enddate` per `nr`. In case the `nr` contains an `enddate` with value `NULL`, it means this `nr` is still active. In short I cannot use `MAX(enddate)` because out of `2013-09-25` and `NULL` it would select the date whereas I need `NULL`.

I tried the following query though it seems that `NULL IN (enddate)` does not return what I suspected. Namely: 'if the array contains at least one value `NULL`...'. In other words, `NULL` should overrank `MAX()`.

```
SELECT nr,
 CASE WHEN NULL IN (enddate) THEN NULL ELSE MAX(enddate) END
 FROM myTable
 GROUP BY nr
```

Does someone know how to replace this expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the query below. It returns NULL before other dates (provided that you put a date great enough) and then restores NULL.

```
SELECT nr, CASE d WHEN '20990101' THEN NULL ELSE d END d
FROM (
    SELECT nr,
    CASE MAX(ISNULL(enddate, '20990101') d
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY nr
)
```

I couldn't check the syntax so there may be small typos.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query. The CTE calculates the maximum date ignoring any nulls, this is then left joined back to the table to see if there is a null value for each nr value. The case statement returns a null if it exists or the maximum date from the CTE.

```
WITH CTE1 AS 
(SELECT nr, MAX(enddate) MaxEnddate
FROM myTable
GROUP BY nr)
  SELECT CTE1.nr,
  CASE WHEN MyTable.enddate IS NULL AND MyTable.NR IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE CTE1.MaxEndDate END AS EndDate
  FROM CTE1
  LEFT JOIN MyTable
  ON MyTable.nr=CTE1.nr
  AND MyTable.enddate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to build off of @Szymon answer a little bit:

```
drop table #temp
create table #temp (MyDate date) insert into #temp (MyDate) values ('1/1/2010'),('1/1/2011'),('1/1/2012'),(NULL)
select * from #temp

SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN MAX(ISNULL(MyDate, '2099-01-01')) = '2099-01-01' THEN NULL ELSE MAX(ISNULL(MyDate, '2099-01-01')) END) as Max_Date
FROM    
    #temp
```

The query replaces a NULL value with '2099-01-01'.  Then, it looks to see if the Max is equal to '2099-01-01' and if so, returns NULL, and otherwise returns the actual Max.